# Correct way to process HTTP Post, then download via HTTP, then save to core data

Tags: ios, json, multithreading, core-data

i have an app that Syncs data to a server. The process is:
1) Convert the local data to JSON
2) Send the local data to the server in a HTTP Post
3) process the response from the server from the HTTP Post in 2) -0 i.e. its the confirmation form the server it did it's processing, and has saved everything OK
4) do a HTTP request for JSON from the server for job updates
5) process this JSON saving to core data

i have tried putting various parts on a background thread so i can release the UI. I keep having intermittent problems, and i think this is because i am using core data on a background thread.

This process is kicked off from a button click, so to keep the UI working i need to do at least some of it in a background thread.

At the moment i send the initial method call to a background thread, and process it all in the background, updating the UI with progress message on the main thread.

can i keep it all as is, but force the core data sections onto the main thread? is that even a good solution? Is it OK to keep everything tin eh background and just put the core core data bits back onto the main thread?

thanks!

edit - I have now made the code more sensible - the VC now kicks off the processing onto a background thread and update the UI via protocol calls from 3 classes that are used to send and download the data.

Each class has it's own managed object context  object, but each class uses the following code to init:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) managedObjectContext
{
    if (!_managedObjectContext)
    {
        mavisFireChecksAppDelegate *appDelegate = (mavisFireChecksAppDelegate *)    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _managedObjectContext=appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

should i change this? the classes are being created on a background thread and although they stay on that thread, the appdeleegate.managedObjectContext is created on app load, so on the main thread. Do i have this correct in my head now? the 3 classes should all init a new MOC not use the appDelegate managed object context as they are running on the background, and the app delegate is created on the main thread?

without actually changing the managed object context init not the classes, it is still erroring once in every 50-100 calls or so. is using the appldelegate.managedobject in the background object the likely cause of the issue

Edit****

Accepted solution in thread below, but some additional useful info for anyone reading this :

I'd just like to add to this incase anyone else ever reads it. I did wrap all CD calls in perform... blocks, but introduced a new error because I wasn't merging the changes correctly on the 2 separate MOC. the link provided by daniel - 
robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data

, is brilliant and showed me my mistake. There is also a CD stack that you can lift off git hub linked at the bottom of the article.

Comment: always perform core data on a background thread when importing data. Are you wrapping all your core data calls in a context perfomBlock: ?

Comment: Take a look at Magical Record, they simplify a lot of the boiler plate you need in core data and they really provide a useful API for performing all CD operations https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: thanks for the replies. This project changed scope dramatically, and while i realised CD was not thread safe as i originally wasn't using threading i didn't look into it much.

i've not used performBlocks. I'll have to look that up properly now.

the import/export routine has 2 sections, one that is it's own class with it's own managed object context and the other in the view controller which kicks it off (bad design i know). It's this bit that is getting the intermittent errors. i don't think i create the  MOC on the main thread,but i'll check that first!

Comment: i'll look up magical record when i've got everything working. once i know it's working, i can introduce something new safely - otherwise i wouldn't know if it's me or magical record or both :)

Comment: Hi, i have added an edit to the OP. i have the VC doing just VC type stuff :)  I have 3 classes doing the import/exports. Each has it's own MOC object, but currently it uses the app delegate.managedObjectContext. The classes run on the background. The appdeleegate is created on the main thread. Just so i get this straight in my head - Should  i change the class MOC init to use a totally new MOC? is this the likely issue? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Core Data from a background thread does not mean that you have achieved concurrency. Consider this code that creates a background thread context:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)createBackgroundContextWithStoreCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator {        
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    context.undoManager = nil;//if you don't need an undo manager always do this for performance boosts
    return context;
}
```

You will see that the context has a concurrency type of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` whereas your UI stuff will typically have `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`

Now that you have a background context you should be aware of the performBlock: (asynchronous) and performBlockAndWait: (synchronous) calls for transacting with Core Data. So your import might look like this:

```
- (void)importStuff:(NSArray *)stuffToImport
       usingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
    andPerformBlock:(void (^)(BOOL madeChanges))completionBlock {
    [context performBlock:^{
       /**
         * do some import stuff
        */
        BOOL madeChanges = [context hasChanges];
        [context save:nil];
        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock(madeChanges);
        }
    }];
}
```

where you would call the import method as follows:

```
NSArray *stuff = //whatever you fetched from server;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //background context;
[importer importStuff:stuff
         usingContext:context
      andPerformBlock:^(BOOL madeChanges){
      if (madeChanges){
          //reload UI
      }
}];
```

Remember, Managed Objects are **NOT** thread-safe. You should always make sure to perform any updates, accesses, or inserts into a contexts performBlock or performBlockAndWait.

Generally I find that blocks are more useful for imports than delegate methods:)

Comment: thanks, that all helps. I've been reading the apple docs as well. i think i get it all now. 

One last question - i fetch to see if a job already exists, then either update or insert. There are a lot of sub objects off the job object. Would you use one big block, or lots of smaller blocks? i always like asking advice:)


By the way - the core data programming guide - concurrency guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

actually says that he best practices have changed which confused me!

Comment: I just saw that, very unfortunate! Just browse around the web I guess, see http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data and http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack

Comment: I'd just like to add to this incase anyone else ever reads it. I did wrap all CD calls in perform... blocks, but introduced a new error because I wasn't merging the changes correctly on the 2 separate MOC.

the link provided by daniel - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data, is brilliant and showed me my mistake. There is also a CD stack that you can lift off git hub linked at the bottom of the article.

Comment: @JamesDawson Thats great news! Rather put this as an edit to your original past rather than hidden in the comments:)